# Continuous Random Variables Table

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

I need some help, I wanted to create a code that will generate the table for the continuous random variables. If possible the code will also generate the graph for the table. Does anyone have an idea on how to code it? Or have any example that is similar to what I asked. Here the pseudo-code that I write and example of the output that I wanted. Thank you for the help!

[image]

[image]

```
Scanner = new Scanner(system.in)
String[] intarray1=intinput.split(“ “); //  Splitting intervals into the table
Print(“Arrary Input :”); // User input intervals value
Int[] intindex = new interger(intarray1.length); // Each relative frequency intervals

Scanner relativeinput = new Scanner(system.in);
String[]relativearray = relativeinput.split(“ “); // Accept input for the relative frequency
Int[] inputindex = new integer(relativearray.length); // Calculate the point for each row using formula

For( i=0; i<= intindex.length; i++) {
    Print(intarray1[i])
    For(j = 0; j< I ; j++){
        Print(relativearray[j])
    }
}
Fx = relativefrequency / rangeinterval; // Calculate fx and split the range between each interval

For(int k = 0; k < relativearray[k]; k++){
    Print(fx);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework or self-assigned problem. I would start this one section at a time. First, produce the data for the table.

Comment: Is the code shown above just pseudocode? You have a upper case `For`. Please read upon Java basics. If you need plotting in Java, there is a nice library called [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) for that.

Comment: I need an example, I need to accept user input, like for how many columns in the table, what is the input for the table column, and then it will calculate the relative frequency and the f(x).